# MySQL retrieving current use info

Tags: php, mysql, string

I have a variable that connects to a MySQL database, set up like this:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","dbName");
```

What I would like to do is have a page, where it would be possible to change the parameters of this. The problem is that the connection variable con is saved in an included file and unfortunately, it is not saved separately as host, user etc., but rather directly written inside the con parameters.

Is there any way of retrieving the 4 parameters backwards from the con parameter which results in a successful connection?

Basically, to make it clear... I have connection created using the con variable and I would like to extract the 4 parameters, I now how to extract host and database, but is it possible to somehow load the username and password into separate PHP string variables?

Comment: You could just pull it out of the text file that is included to create the connection.

Comment: You need to require the document where those variables are declared

Comment: Oh.... yes... of course... just did not occur to me, because it is actually a php file ... of course I could, thanks!